# Titles/Album names that are longer than 30 bytes

Tags: python, id3

Dunno if this is the right place.

I'm trying to read the metadata of ID3V1 tags and some titles are longer than 30 bytes and other programs have no problems reading the complete title. I've checked id3.org but haven't been able to find anything helpful. How do I go about reading the complete title?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "/media/Music/RZ"
files = [join(path, f) for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and f.endswith("mp3")]

for f in files:
    with open(f, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(-128, 2)
        data = f.read()

        if data[:3] == b"TAG":
            title = data[3:33].decode("UTF-8")
            artist = data[33:63].decode("UTF-8")
            album = data[63:93].decode("UTF-8")
```

printing title results in

```
Super-Doom-Hex-Gloom Part One
Get Your Boots On ! That's The
Wurdalak
In The Age Of The Consegrated 
A Hearse That Overturns With T
Well, Everybody's Fucking In A
Satanic Cyanide ! The Killer R
The Life And Times Of A Teenag
The Last Of The Demons Defeate
Medication For The Melancholy
The Hideous Exhibitions Of A D
In The Bone Pile
```

Comment: How are you trying to read the metadata currently?  Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: See edit, just simple code based on regular ID3V1, from the last 128 bytes in valid mp3.

Comment: Perhaps you should use mutagen.easyid3, instead of trying to seek around in the binary yourself?

Comment: The id3v1 title can not be longer then 30 bytes according the specification. If a title is longer, it's a) not a ID3v1 tag or b) out of definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PeterCo said in their comment, you *are* reading the complete title, as far as the ID3v1 tag knows. There are a few unofficial extensions to the standard that allow slightly longer fields (the "[extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Extended_tag) [tag](https://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/what-are-id3-tags-all-about/#id3v1ext)" being slightly better-known than [ID3v1.2](http://www.birdcagesoft.com/ID3v12.txt) or [ID3v1.3](http://lib313.sourceforge.net/id3v13.html)), but none of them are at all common – to the point where I'd be surprised if your test files included them. My guess is that the programs that show the complete titles are actually taking it from an ID3v2 tag, which (despite the name) has very little in common with ID3v1.

If you just want something to make sure the right files are following the right path through a larger program, then I'd recommend sticking with what you have; it's clear and lightweight. Same if you *only* care about the ID3v1 tag. If you *are* doing something with the full title, though, your best bet by far would be to use one of the [existing libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsefulModules#ID3_Handling). I actually find it kind of fun to implement the specification, but there's no arguing against the fact that it's an entire project on its own.

---

That said, if you know you'll never want anything but the title (or a predictable, limited selection of other near-ubiquitous text fields), you might be able to naively scan through the file looking for the proper headers, as described below. I hope you'll forgive me not writing actual code, but it's been a while since I've written Python. If you do go with this, I'd really recommend checking out the [official](http://id3.org/d3v2.3.0) [specifications](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) to have a better idea of what all you'll be skipping over.

The first thing you'll want to do is check the first three bytes of the file. If they aren't `49 44 33` (`ID3` in ASCII) then it probably doesn't have an ID3v2 tag (or it's malformed) and you may as well fall back on the ID3v1. While you're here, you may want to check the fourth byte – it will be either `03` or `04`, depending on which version the file uses. There's a few differences between them that could come into play once we get to the text, but for now just make sure that the *second* byte after that (the sixth in the file) is less than 128, especially if the version byte is `03`; you don't want to deal with reversing unsynchronization, believe me.

Once you've verified that, just start running through the file until you find the sequence `54 49 54 32` (`TIT2` representing "Text tITle 2" which is actually the number we want; alternatively, you might want to match `54 50 45 31` `TPE1` for the artist or `54 41 4C 42` `TALB` for the album, or look for other IDs in the specs). That's not a particularly common sequence, but just to be sure you don't run into anything that's been saved in a comment or anything, you'll probably want to be sure the next several bytes follow `00 00 0_ __ _0 00` – and even that's not completely foolproof. Anyway, the first four bytes are the size, and while it's *technically* possible that the top two-and-a-half won't be `00 00 0`, that would require a ridiculously long string of text (more than 2047 bytes) or way too much padding; the last two indicate special properties about the field, and while it's again possible that the zeros aren't actually zeros, that would mean that there's something not straightforward about how the field is encoded, and if you try to handle that, you may as well think about implementing the entire standard.

Read the next byte. It indicates how the text is encoded: `00` means [ISO-8859-1](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ISO-8859-1), `01` means UTF-16 beginning with a byte-order-marker, `02` is big-endian UTF-16 without a byte marker, and `03` is UTF-8. You could ignore any of those you don't want to deal with, but ID3v2.3 only supports the first two, and there's not really any benefit to ignoring UTF-16BE if you already recognize UTF-16 with BOM (and enough programs wrote tags in that encoding that you'll want to catch it), or UTF-8 if you recognize ISO-8859-1.

After that is where that version byte really comes into play. If you're in ID3v2.3, you only need to read until the first null character (not byte; for the UTF-16 encodings only, that means looking for two consecutive `00` bytes). If you're in ID3v2.4, you'll need to decide between that simple approach or fully supporting the multiple values the new version supports. I recommend the first since – believe it or not – I'm trying to keep this implementation concise, but for completeness, the other requires remembering the size bytes from two paragraphs back, shifting the third (the first half-blank) left by *7* bits (or multiplying by 128) and adding the fourth (the full blank), reading that many bytes (not characters), decoding them according to the previous paragraph, and splitting the string on null characters (not bytes).

And then, finally, you have your full title. If you want to keep looking for another text tag (like the author or album I gave way up there), then you'll need to keep scanning through the rest of the file to find their headers. Otherwise, just jump to the ID3v1 tag and revel in how simple it is to get the truncated values.